# Non existence of a complex function from exterior of unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Suppose $f$:{$z\in \mathbb C:|z|>1$}$\rightarrow\mathbb C$, $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$. Prove that there doesn't exist an entire function $g(z)$ s.t. $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$ with $|z|>1$.

I really do not have any clue how to prove this. I tried it using Identity theorem but that gives me $h(z)=f(z)-g(z)$ identically zero on $\mathbb C$. Any help appreciated!! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $g(z)=1/z$ on exterior of unit disk then it's clearly bounded there. On the other hand, $g$ must also be bounded on closed unit disk since it's continuous there. Hence $g$ is bounded entire, this is a contradiction.

Comment: ..$g(z)=1/z$ has a pole at $z=0$ so how it is bounded in $|z|\leq 1$?

Comment: I only said $g=1/z$ on the exterior of unit disk. For $|z|\le 1$, we have no information of $g$ (except that it must be analytic in $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$). But inside the closed unit disk, continuity of $g$ gives its boundedness (since closed unit disk is compact and continuous function sends compact to compact, which means it's bounded). I'm not saying $g=1/z$ for $|z|\le 1$.

Comment: ok..thanks I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

You could define $\hat{f}(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ on $D=\mathbb C-\{0\}$.  If $g$ existed and was equal to $f$ on $C=\{z\in\mathbb C:\|z\|>1\}$, then it'd be equal to $\hat{f}$ on $C\subset D$, so that it equals $\hat{f}$ on $D$.  But there's no value you could assign to $g(0)$ that'd make this continuous at $0$.